# Bitmap Overlay has a weird grid-like pattern when zoomed out

Tags: texture, bitmap

I did a bitmap of a cloud texture in photoshop so i could bring it over to illustrator to overlay it on a poster. the texture on the poster seemed fine in illustrator but once i exported it as a jpeg/pdf it had a weird grid-like pattern when zoomed out. heres the picture of the weird grid-like pattern that i screenshotted

anyway to fix this? or is this inevitable
[image]

Comment: Common visual issue because the artwork can't be antialiased well enough at zoom levels. Shouldn't matter though if it looks fine at 100%.

Comment: Bitmap (1-bit) dithering looks cool, but comes with a lot of trouble. On screen it only looks correct when viewed at 100%. Below that you get these moiré patterns. On print (especially offset) it's not really advisable to use. Lots of pitfalls if you aren't aware of the halftoning used and other technical stuff. Is your artwork for web or print?

Answer (score 1):

See this cloth example: [How can moiré effects be diminished in clothing photographs?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96252/how-can-moir%c3%a9-effects-be-diminished-in-clothing-photographs)

And this fake engraving example: [image]

There a repeating pattern of the target interferes with the rasterization pattern of the final image. It's the Moire effect. The fake engraving example seems different in different zoom levels on the screen. The cloth example shows the seen result when a fabric pattern is shown in a low resolution image.

The cases are different. The engraving example generates the effect when you watch the attached image. The cloth example shows a photo of already generated effect.

One possibility is to kill the sharpness of the pattern in the image by applying low pass filtering. Graphic programs have a form of low-pass filtering - the blur. It's not especially frequency selective, but it can work.

Your rasterized texture pattern has something repeating - probably that's inherited from its original bitmap size. Try to apply blur to your bitmap texture image or generate it with different rasterization density (=pixel dimensions) if you can reach a non-rasterized version of it.

There's no need to do anything if the Moire is generated in the final rendering to the screen and the image looks right in its usual watching pixel dimensions.